# Make Eclipse visible to system

Tags: 16.04, unity, eclipse

I have installed `Eclipse` with standard installer in folder:

```
~/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse
```

Uniti don't see eclipse and terminals don't see `Eclipse`. If I type `eclipse` command with full path - it runs fine.

I suppose I need to set PATH environment variable for this reason. But where is the best way to do that? I found several places in Ubuntu where I can do that:

```
.bashrc
/etc/bash.bashrc
.bash_profile
.profile
/etc/profile.d
/etc/environment
```

Which is right place?

How to make `Unity` see `Eclipse` when I push start button?

UPD

I have created symbolic link to eclipse binary:

```
 sudo ln ~/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse eclipse
```

Now I have message during Eclipse start:

> The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its  companion
>   shared library.

Answer (score 2):

To add it to your path you can simply create a link in `/usr/bin`

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s /home/vico/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse eclipse
```

To add it to the dash you need a .desktop file for eclipse:

`gedit ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`

Paste this content to the file and edit Exec and Icon values:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=** probably/home/vico/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse/icon.xpm **
Exec= ** probably/home/vico/eclipse/eclipse **
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```

Comment: Can I write just ~/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse eclipse instead /home/vico/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse eclipse   ?

Comment: Yes you can use that as well. `~/` is will just fet expanded to `/home/YourUser`.

Comment: link does not help. More details in question body UPD

Comment: eclipse.desktop not helped. Actually ~/.local/share/applications/ was totally empty and eclipse.desktop was the first file there